# Include '-' in regex search with \w+ . Python

Tags: python, regex, search, attributeerror

```
k = 'a bunch of data and then name ""Serpin-ps""'        
print re.search(r'name\s""(\w+)""',k).group(1)
```

gives:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

desired_output = `'Serpin-ps'`

Makes sense because there is a '-' in the text.

Is there anyway to get regex to incorporate the '-' along with all the other alphanumeric characters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put pre-set character classes like `\w` into explicit character classes. So:

```
print re.search(r'name\s""([-\w]+)""',k).group(1)
```

Comment: what does the [] do? so any character put before the \w will work during the search?

Comment: @draconisthe0ry - It's called a "character class." `[abc123]` would match exactly one character: `a`, `b`, `c`, `1`, `2`, or `3`. (Repetition is cancelled out, _e.g._ `[foobar]` will match an `o` but not two.) You can also include special character classes like `\w` and `\d`. You can also include ranges, as in `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. To further exemplify, `\w+` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` (note the underscore). To prevent the `-` from being interpreted as a range operator within character classes, the literal `-` must appear first or last in a character class. So `[\w-]` would have worked as well.

Comment: awesome! i found some other weird names in my file with . () and stuff.  i just put them along with the - and it worked.  thanks a million

Comment: @draconisthe0ry: There are a few other characters that are treated specially within a character class besides `-` (e.g., `]`, `^`). If you need the reference details (e.g., to see which other characters besides `-` have to be treated specially within a character class), see [Regular Expression Syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax). Also, [Regular Expression HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#regex-howto) in the docs explains this, but I think acheong87's explanation is clearer than the official one.